# Flex Remoting Error

Tags: actionscript

I was trying to connect Flex to Backend Java and I was trying to call a method in one of the classe in the Backend java  and it was returning

Faultcode:Server.Processing

java.lang.NullPointerException : null

In the root cause everything is null .

.I have checked everything from RemotingConfig to the Flex calling service .

roReporting = new MeteringRemoteObject("ReportingServices");
roReporting.source = "reportmgmt.Reporting";
roReporting.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE,invokeHandler);
roReporting["getReportData"].addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,graphResultHandler);
roReporting["getReportData"].addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, graphFaultHandler);
In the metering Remote Object I have written a code to connect to the back end .

Can somebody please let me know whether you have come across this problem .

Thanks ,
SUDEEP KUMAR

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Flex or Flex Remoting. Your Java service just throws a NullPointerException. Check the code, use your debugger or add some debug log statements to the service method in question.